# I've created a 3 x 3, Noughts and crosses game that works but now I'm trying to change it to fundamentally do the sae thing but on a 4 x 4 grid

Tags: python

I've Increased the board array to allow for it but I've got functions that display and clear the board which I tried to increase the parameters to display the new board but it still throwing errors out saying my list is out of index. If ore info is needed please ask.

```
Board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

def DisplayBoard(Board):
    print('  | 1 2 3 4')
    print('--+---------')
    for Row in range(1,5):
        print(Row, '|', end=' ')
        for Column in range(1,5):
            print(Board[Column][Row], end=' ')
        print( )
    print('\n')

def ClearBoard(Board):
    for Row in range(0,4):
        for Column in range(0,4):
            Board[Column][Row] = ' '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `range(1, 5)` to `range(0, 4)` like you have in your other function. Note also that `range(0,4)` does the same thing as `range(4)`.